# Social network database delete record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple database project that describes a social network. I have Entities like: Profile, Friendship, Photo, Post, etc... This project is for university.

I have developed all the stuff but i miss a sql query i'm not able to figure out. This is what my teacher wants:

Frienships and Photos can be deleted by the owner user. Once deleted, they are maintained for 6 months before being definitely deleted.

How can i do that?

I edit my question to fit stackoverflow's TOS.

I have this tables:

Profile(Id, Name, Surname, WorkAt, StudyAt, LiveAt, ProfilePhoto)

Id is the primary key.

Friendship(FriendA, FriendB, date, state)

FriendA, FriendB are foreign keys to ID of Profile.

I was thinking something like that:

```
delete 
from Friendship
where state = deleted and date .... something
```

I don't know how to go on, because i don't know ho can i get today date in sql.

Comment: If you have no clue at all, you should ask your teacher for hints. If you have tried something, but are stuck, please show us what you tried and let us know what the specific problem is.

Comment: The magic word you're looking for is SYSDATE, a function to return today's date.  It's in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions191.htm#sthref1621

Comment: Google soft delete.  That should give you some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sorts of delete here. When the user deletes the photo you need to run an update to flag the record as deleted. You might model this by setting `DateDeleted` to `Sysdate`. When displaying you would need to check `DateDeleted` is `null`.

Periodically you actually delete the records by looking for any where `DateDeleted` is more than 6 months ago.